# Popup is not showing up properly in iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, uialertcontroller

After using below code popup is not coming properly in some devices like iPhone 4s, iPad etc....it works properly in iPhone 6.

Below is the code,

```
UIAlertController *alert1 = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Set Bookmark" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    Definition *toBookmark = [appDelegate.encyclopedia getByIdxTerm:mydef.idxterm];

    BOOL bBook = [[appDelegate prefsdb] addBookmark:[[appDelegate encyclopedia] objectInListAtIndex:toBookmark.encIdx]];

    [alert1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
    [alert1 dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}];

[alert1 addAction:ok];
[alert1 addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert1 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

before i was using UIActionsheet which is deprecated in iOS 8....and i am comping with iOS 8.

**screenshot from iPhone 4s**

[image]

screenshot from iPhone 5

[image]

it should come like iphone5....Please help

Comment: Does the 4S run an iOS version prior to 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternate solution : change preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet to preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert, if you do't mind with the design of layout.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a Height constraint might fix it:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:alert1.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:self.view.frame.size.height];
[alert1.view addConstraint:constraint];
```